# Error al traer método de un Fragment desde una Actividad - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment, kotlin

Estoy tratando de llamar a un método que está dentro de mi fragmento, el método es el siguiente:

```js
fun onMyKeyUp(key:Int, event:KeyEvent )
    {
        //define your statement like
        if (Integer.parseInt(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK) > 5
            && key == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
            && event.repeatCount == 0
        ) {
            AlertDialog.Builder (context)
                .setTitle("Title")
                .setMessage("Do you really want to Exit?")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, object : DialogInterface.OnClickListener {

                    override fun onClick(dialog: DialogInterface?, which: Int) {
                        requireActivity().finish();
                    }

                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null).show();
        }

    }
```

Se supone que ese método maneja el botón de atrás mostrando un dialogo, pero al llamar desde mi actividad principal me sale el error: **kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type com.example.myapplication.ui.home.HomeFragment**

Mi código para llamar a dicho método desde la actividad es el siguiente:

```js
override fun onKeyUp(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
        val fragment:HomeFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_home) as HomeFragment
        fragment.onMyKeyUp(keyCode, event)
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event)
    }
```

Si alguien me podría guiar en ésta parte porque no se porqué me sale dicho error si estoy llamando de la forma correcta al método.

Answer (score 0):

Parece que el problema puede estar en lo siguiente.

```
override fun onKeyUp(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
    val fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_home)
    if(fragment != null && fragment is HomeFragment)
        fragment.onMyKeyUp(keyCode, event)
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event)
}
```

Agrega la validación que no es null y luego verifica que es de tipo `HomeFragment`, puede que tu activity tenga muchos fragments y puede que no sepas que fragment es el actual, entonces cuando le casteas a `HomeFragment` ocurre un error porque lo estas forzando, lo más recomendable es preguntar si es de este tipo y luego castearlo. Por otro lado, puede que también el error este en `R.id.fragment_home` que le pasas a `fragmentManager.findFragmentById`, recordemos que ese id que le pasa al método es de tu **contenedor**, generalmente es un frameLayout. Entonces ese `id` que tiene el fragmentolayout es el que se tiene que pasar a ese método.

**Update**

Bueno si estas utilizando navigation components, podrías intentar el siguiente código:

```
val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment) 

            val currentDestination = navController.currentDestination

            if (currentDestination?.id == R.id.homeFragment) {

                val navHostFragment =
                    supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment)


                val homeFragment: HomeFragment? =
                    navHostFragment?.childFragmentManager?.fragments?.get(0) as HomeFragment?
               
               homeFragment.onMyKeyUp(keyCode, event)
                
            }
```

Explicacion:

- En `val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)`  buscamos el controler, aqui deberias reemplazar el `R.id.nav_host_fragment` por el id que tienes, este es el id de tu  que defines en tu activity para que contenga a todos los fragments que definas en tu navgraph
- Una vez que obtenemos el navController, vamos a preguntar el currentDestionantion a través del id. Como sabemos si utilizamos un navGraph, el xml empieza con un root de `<navigation>` y sus hijos son `<fragment>` entonces ese es el id que vamos a poner, el de la etiqueta `<fragment>` que corresponde a tu homefragment, supongo que es algo como `R.id.homeFragment`, si es distinto, solo reemplazado por el que tienes.
- Ahora buscamos el `navHostFragment` , como en el primer paso de la descripción le pasamos el id de tu fragment que esta en tu activity que contendrá a todos los fragments definidos en tu navGraph
- Finalmente ahora que ya tenemos el navHostFragment, pasemos a buscar al HomeFragment, si bien como comentamos anterior mente este navGraph tiene un **arreglo de fragments**, por lo tanto vamos a buscarlo. Podemos buscarlo por su id, o en el ejemplo que te paso accedo a la posición `0`, asumiendo que HomeFragment, es el primer fragment que se setea a tu navgraph. Ahora en tu caso dependiendo de tu lógica puedes buscarlo por id, por posición o como mejor se te acomode.

Espero te ayude :)

Comment: No me funciona, ¿Tu crees que sea porque estoy trabajando con NavigationComponents?

Comment: Osea si me reconoce la función desde ese fragmento pero siempre me bota ese error

Comment: @Nik actualice la respuesta :)